# Why does MySQL DATE_FORMAT print a blank result?

Tags: perl, dbi

For the past couple of hours I've been trying to format a MySQL timestamp using `DATE_FORMAT` and it doesn't do anything!

Perl Code:

```
use CGI;
use DBI;

my $q = new CGI;

# Database connection goes here

my $sth_select = $dbh->prepare(
    "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%m/%d/%y') FROM foo"
);

$sth_select->execute() || die "Unable to execute query: $dbh->errstr";

if (my $ref = $sth_select->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    print $q->header;
    print " TIME: $ref->{timestamp}";
    exit;
}
```

Results

```
TIME:
```

It doesn't print the formatted time at all, *it is blank*!

When I attempt to print the timestamp it doesn't print anything, but if I were to remove `DATA_FORMAT` and just simply do a `SELECT timestamp FROM foo`, then it prints the timestamp just fine, albeit not formatted though. Can somebody provide their insight on this matter, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hash returned has as keys column headers as provided by the database.  When using a function like that, the column header is actually "DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%m/%d/%y')".
Try modifying your SQL to be:

```
my $sth_select = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%m/%d/%y') AS timestamp FROM foo");
```

Comment: Or you could use `fetchrow_array`  or `fetchrow_arrayref`, which don't care about column names.

Comment: Or: `foreach my $key (keys %$ref) { print "$key = $ref->{$key}\n"; }`

Comment: You sir just solved my problem! I was trying the 'AS' argument but instead of using 'AS timestamp' I was using 'AS formatted_timestamp'. Nevertheless I tried your suggestion and worked like a charm! If ever I meet you one day the beer is on me! Thanks one hell of bunch!

Comment: Comment directed @ysth but thanks for the insight too Jonathan!